# VueJS: How I can specify scope on Sentry?

Tags: vue.js, sentry

I'm using `@sentry/vue` and I'm trying to catch only the errors that come from my module because currently I'm catching all the errors from the application.

On the Sentry documentation I can't find how to limit the scope to restrict and capture only the errors from my module.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: You can try `trackComponents` and set needed array of components.